# not understandable pointers errors

Tags: c, pointers

I'm getting two errors and I don't know how to fix them.

```
error 1: 
incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'char *'  
error 2: 
invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'int')|
```

I appreciate any help! 
thanks!

```c
void play(int *boom_number, char *players)
{
    int y;
    char temp;
    int *sorting_pointer = &players[LENGTH-1];
    int current_index=0;
    while (sorting_pointer!=players[0])
    {
        int position=((&sorting_pointer-&players[0])/sizeof(int));
        current_index=boom_number%position
        char temp[]=players[current_index]
        for (y=current_index; y<position;y++)
        {
            players[y]=players[y+1]
        }
        players[position]=temp
        *sorting_pointer--
    }
}
```

Comment: You have some syntax errors: better to copy copy/paste the actual code (and show which lines the compiler does not like).

Comment: `*sorting_pointer--` should probably be `sorting_pointer--;`

Comment: `char temp[]=players[current_index]` should probably be `temp=players[current_index];`

Comment: Other lines are missing `;` too.

Comment: `int *sorting_pointer = &players[LENGTH-1];` is assigning a `char*` to `int*`. The code is riddled with errors. Please start over, add lines the the function one by one, checking exactly what each line does.

Comment: I hereby allow you to format your code properly in further questions yourself. ^^

Answer (score 2):

You should compile with maximum warnings:

**Clang**

```
$ clang -Weverything -c test.c
test.c:7:10: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    int *sorting_pointer = &players[LENGTH-1];
         ^                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:9:27: warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('int *' and 'int')
    while (sorting_pointer!=players[0])
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ ~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:11:40: error: 'int **' and 'char *' are not pointers to compatible types
        int position=((&sorting_pointer-&players[0])/sizeof(int));
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:12:34: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'int')
        current_index=boom_number%position
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

**GCC**

```
$ gcc -Wall -c test.c
test.c: In function ‘play’:
test.c:7:28: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     int *sorting_pointer = &players[LENGTH-1];
                            ^
test.c:9:27: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     while (sorting_pointer!=players[0])
                           ^~
test.c:11:40: error: invalid operands to binary - (have ‘int **’ and ‘char *’)
         int position=((&sorting_pointer-&players[0])/sizeof(int));
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:12:34: error: invalid operands to binary % (have ‘int *’ and ‘int’)
         current_index=boom_number%position
                                  ^
test.c:13:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘char’
         char temp[]=players[current_index]
         ^~~~
test.c:8:9: warning: variable ‘current_index’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int current_index=0;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:6:10: warning: unused variable ‘temp’ [-Wunused-variable]
     char temp;
          ^~~~
test.c:5:9: warning: unused variable ‘y’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int y;
```

As far as fixing your errors...

Here:

```
void play(int *boom_number, char *players)
{
    ...
    int *sorting_pointer = &players[LENGTH - 1];
    int position = ((&sorting_pointer - &players[0]) / sizeof(int));
    ...
}
```

You probably mean to do something like:

```
void play(int *boom_number, char *players)
{
    ...
    char *sorting_pointer = &players[LENGTH - 1];
    size_t length = sorting_pointer - &players[0];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite int and char are compatible types and can be implicitly converted from int to char and conversely, pointers don't have any implicit conversion even it's stored types have. Consider:

```
//int* c = &b;      //doesn't work, because &b is char *
//char* d = &a;     // doesn't work, a is int *
int* c = (int*)& b;  //compiled
char* d = (char*)& d;  //compiled
cout << *c << " " << *d << endl;
```

Unfortunately, explicit C-conversion cause undefined behaviour in these pointers, so we get the undesirable output:
    9-858993567 B

C++ conversion more reliable in this case, so static_cast instead of C-conversion cause a compilation error

```
int * c = static_cast<int*>(&a); // error, invalid type conversion
char * d = static_cast<char*>(&b); // error, invalid type conversion
```

Only reinterpret_cast allows you to do such a thing.
So, you cannot store in a pointer a value which type is not a pointer type.

Comment: This question is tagged C and not C++. Why are you using and discussing `cout`, `static_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: yeah, sorry, my bad. But if we'll down the second part, I state that there's no such conversion in C too, as iI know.

Comment: There are some implicit conversions of pointers in C: To and from `void *` and adding qualifiers.